# all numbers in for loop array need to be displayed

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need help to make sure that all numbers in my array are displayed because only the first 2 are being displayed.

```
function tizer(n) {
  var firstArray = (""+n).split('');
  var newArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
    newArray[i] = parseInt(firstArray.shift(),10);
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(tizer(8675));
```

Result: `[8,6]`

Expected: `[8,6,7,5]`

Comment: Could you add some test cases? Specifically, what you used as an input to get this result.

Comment: how do I do it .I am new here .

Comment: Just edit your post and say "This is my input, this is my output, and this is what I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much simpler than you thought. You should have used `firstArray[i]` instead of `firstArray.shift()`.

```js
function tizer(n) {
  var firstArray = (""+n).split('');
  var newArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
    newArray[i] = parseInt(firstArray[i],10);
  }
  
  // Sort odd first
  var arraySorted = [...newArray.filter(item => item%2 == 1), ...newArray.filter(item => item%2 == 0)]
  
  return arraySorted;
}

console.log(tizer(8675));
```

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to upvote my answer. Thanks.

Comment: If you can me out with this that will be great. I am new to javascript.JavaScript
Write a mySort function which takes in an array integers, and should return an array of the inputed integers sorted such that the odd numbers come first and even numbers come last.

For exampl1e:

mySort( [90, 45, 66, 'bye', 100.5] )
should return

[45, 66, 90, 100]

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm out of home. When I get back I can help you with that.

Comment: alright ,thanks .Will send the code I have done for it shortly.

Comment: Hello @ohbabie, I have added one line of code to sort the odds first.

Comment: Thank you. I have been able to sort that out. But I need solution to this please .Will appreciate.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54727336/counts-how-many-different-ways-you-can-make-change-for-an-amount-of-money

Comment: how do i do that .I am new here.

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a `.map(Number)` after you `.split`

```js
function tizer(n) {
  return (n + '').split('').map(Number);
}

console.log(tizer(8675));
```